# Normal layout - adapting layout_toRightOf for 4" and 4,7" screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following example: an edittext and on the right an imagebutton. The only solution I have now is to design for the 4" screen.

So the look on the 4" screen is like that:

[image]

and the 4,7" screen:

[image]

Is there a solution to draw the width of the edittext to the end right and still see the imagebutton? I've tried to play with width = wrap_content or match_parent + marginRight but I don't get anywhere:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtl"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Test enter text to modify"
        android:textSize="@dimen/a_normal"
        android:textColor="#0000ff"
        android:inputType="textWebEditText"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/sel_email"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/edtl"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/edtl"
        android:src="@mipmap/info"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Test enter text to modify text1 text2 text3 text4"
        android:textSize="@dimen/a_normal"
        android:textColor="#0000ff"
        android:inputType="textWebEditText"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/edtl"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@id/edtl"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/edtl"
        android:src="@mipmap/info"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

which looks like that. close: i'm missing the gap between the edittext and the imagebutton.

[image]

Comment: Use constraint layout. It's work for all screen.

Comment: Which layout are you using ? Please post full XML file :-)

Comment: I looked briefly at it just now. It sounds nice. Not too complex?

Comment: @Sachin: see the edit change. just a Relativelayout

Comment: @narb If you want to use constraint layout than m post my answer.

Comment: close: i'm missing the gap between the edittext and the imagebutton.than put marginLeft to imagebutton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this, tried and working -

```
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/edtl"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Test enter text to modify"
        android:textColor="#0000ff"
        android:inputType="textWebEditText"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/info"
        />
```

Comment: Can you tell me what the difference is between this and my answer?

Comment: Hi, @H.Brooks !! Yes, the answer is kinda same. I was testing on Android Studio and didn't look closely to your answer because OP mentioned it didn't work. The answer is not copied from yours. Sorry about it anyway !!

Comment: No problem, I thought you just copied my answer.

Comment: and the winner is :) I think the difference is the order. Many thanks to you two.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"        
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/info"
        android:hint="Test enter text to modify"
        android:textSize="@dimen/a_normal"
        android:textColor="#0000ff"
        android:inputType="textWebEditText"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:margin_left="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:alignParentRight="true"
        android:alignParentEnd="true"       
        android:src="@mipmap/info"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This will make the `EditText` stay left of the `ImageButton` and take up the remainder of the width.

Comment: still working on it ;) it's not showing the edittext. i removed the alignstart which is a leftover and added @id/info in the edittext but it's the same.

Comment: not sure why but I have still the same issue. Sachin's response works.